# Function that turns sequence into list

Tags: python, functional-programming, toolz

We know that

```
list(map(f,[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]))
```

is equivalent to

```
[f(1,3,6),f(2,4,7)]
```

I want to know if there is built-in function `tolist` that is equivalent to `[]`, so that

```
tolist(a,b,c,d)
```

is equivalent to `[a,b,c,d]`.

I think such a function is useful in functional programming. Because many functions take list parameter instead of sequence.

Of course, a simple custom way is `lambda *x:list(x)`, but I always feels it is syntactically cumbersome, especially use it in functional programming style like

```
map(lambda *x:list(x),[1,2],[3,4],[6,7])
```

So my question is that if there is no such built-in `tolist`, whether we could build it on the fly more elegantly using FP packages like `toolz`?

PS: What I actually want to achieve is threaded version of add (I know numpy, but I don't want to use it at the moment)

```
from toolz.curried import *
import operator as op
def addwise(*args):
    return list(map(compose(reduce(op.add),lambda *x:list(x)),*args))
```

then

```
addwise([1,2],[3,4],[6,7])
```

will gives

```
[10, 13]
```

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin.  You can write it as `def tolist(*args): return list(args)`, but I can't see why you would want to (you can do most of the things with a tuple that you can with a list).

Comment: In particular, the arguments to `map` are *iterables*, not lists.

Comment: Hi, @MartinBonner. Thank you very much for reply. But I don't understand your "you can do most of the things with a tuple that you can with a list". What does it mean? And is it possible to make `addwise` more succinct(especially get rid of lambda)?

Comment: you could write it as `lambda*x:x`, which 7 chars shorter...

Comment: @georgexsh you are right! +1

Answer (score 1):

If

> function is useful (....) Because many functions take list parameter

it is a good sign that `lambda` expression is not a right fit. You don't want to repeat yourself every time you want to apply this pattern.

Sadly we are far from Clojure conciseness:

```
user=> (map + [1 2] [3 4] [6 7])
(10 13)
```

but we can still express it in a fairly Pythonic and elegant way:

```
def apply(f):
    def _(*args):
        return f(args)
    return _
```

which can be used as:

```
from toolz.curried import reduce 

map(apply(reduce(op.add)), [1,2], [3,4], [6,7])
```

or even better

```
map(apply(sum), [1,2], [3,4], [6,7])
```

although in this case `map`, can be combined with `zip`:

```
map(sum, zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 7])))
```